# User Input into an Array

Tags: c++, arrays

Why won't this put the users integer of `54321` individually into the array `integer[1][5]` as, `[5][4][3][2][1]`? It instead puts `54321` into ONE array block.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int integer[1][5];
    int number;

    cout << "Please enter an integer: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                cin >> integer[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        {
           for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                cout << integer[i][j]<< " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
//why wont this output an integer of 12345 individually into an array of [1][5]?
```

Comment: Because `54321` is a single valid integer as far as the  `operator >>` you're invoking is concerned.

Comment: And this implies that you have to put spaces between your input numbers to make this work. Or, alternatively, read a single `int` and then cut it into digits by dividing with powers of 10.

Comment: hey have you found any solution???

Comment: Muhammad Irfan and Andras Deak Thank you...you have been great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test this new  code, I have used char array to take input 12345 then converted it into integer array and then printed it in reverse order to achieve what you need, you can alter position of 12345 to 54321 in 2nd for loop and then modify 3rd loop to print numbers from j=0 to j<5

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char cinteger[5];
    int number[5];

    cout << "Please enter an integer: " << endl;

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        cin >> cinteger[j];

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        number[j]= cinteger[j] - '0';
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int j = 5; j > 0; j--){
        cout << "[";
        cout << number[j-1]<< "] ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now this is much better, this is what I think OP meant:)

Comment: and please can you mark this answer as correct if you think it is, so that others can also take help from it?

Comment: just did, sorry about that. Im still new to stackoverflow.com, great website!

Comment: is something wrong with the answer? you just unaccepted it?

Answer (score 0):

54321 is considered as an integer in it of itself.
In order to achieve [5][4][3][2][1] in the array in this scenario, the user has to type each integer individually.
5
*Enter*
4
*Enter*
3
*Enter*
2
*Enter*
1
*Enter*

Comment: Note that any whitespace is OK between the digits, not just newline.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you must have space (or white character) between every number you want to enter.
Parser see it like one number not like five digits...

Answer (score 0):

Your method of receiving the input requires you to press "enter" after every submission of each integer.

Either use a different method to acquire data from the user, or expect the user to press enter after every individual integer.

An alternative, if you want to keep using std::cin, would be to acquire the data before the for-loop, right after the prompt, and then find the individual integers you want using the for-loops.

Example: Finding the 1's digit.

```
int data[5], input, size;

cout<<"Enter the data: ";
cin>>input;

for(size = 0; size < 5; ++size){//Assumes array limit = 5.
    data[size] = input%10;
    input = input/10;
    if(input==0)
        break;//Escape if fewer characters than 5 entered.
}
```

Remember that, index 0 will contain your smallest digit and index 5 will contain your largest digit:
"21,354" will be stored as {4,5,3,1,2} where value 5 is at index 1. So printing will require a reverse for-loop.

Something like this:

```
for(int i = size; i >= 0; --i){
    cout<<data[i]<<' ';
}
cout<<endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

You are declaring your 2-D Array incorrectly to get the result that you would like. Try switching your array so it looks like this.

```
int integer[5][1];
```

This is also a good reference to better understand basic array functionality. 
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Comment: If you read the other answers/comments, you'll see that there's a much more fundamental problem. What's more, I'm not sure I see the error you are talking about.

Comment: I appreciate all the help. I will try all these out when I get home in a couple and reply back.